# Using wwwhisper for a Django app in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, wwwhisper

it is possible to use wwwhisper add-on for a Django app? In that case, where can I find any guide about how to configure it? I've already installed the add-on, but I don't know how to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wwwhisper author here. <strike>The add-on works only with Ruby and Node.js applications on Heroku.</strike> The recently released [wwwhisper buildpack](https://github.com/wwwhisper-auth/wwwhisper-heroku-buildpack) allows to use the wwwhisper add-on with any language and framework supported by Heroku including Django.

To enable the buildpack, execute:

```
heroku buildpacks:add auth/wwwhisper
git commit --allow-empty -m "Enable wwwhisper buildpack."
# Replace 'heroku' with the name of your Heroku remote, and 'main' with
# the name of the branch to deploy to Heroku:
git push heroku main
```

Heroku [devcenter documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/wwwhisper#enabling-the-wwwhisper-buildpack) has more details